# How can make changes to a hard drive being shared with a Windows machine?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, windows

So, this may be a unique issue and goes to show my ineptitude with Apple products. But, I have a hard drive that I share with my Windows PC that I use for storing all my pictures, music, and movies. The problem is that on OSX I'm not able to make any changes to the drive. I can't rename, add to it, or delete anything. I checked the Get Info on it, and for security it says I can only Read.

I've Googled all sorts of stuff and everything just keeps telling me to "click the lock". What lock?! Am I completely missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What starsky_70 is saying is that it is likely that the external drive is formatted NTFS, and out of the box NTFS is read only on Mac OS X. But if you formatted it exFAT then it would be read/write on both operating systems without the need for additional software.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks man. Is it possible to change the format without losing all the data?

Comment: Nope, any time you change the file system you format the drive and erase it. That would be the annoying part... sigh.

Answer (score 0):

You must install FUSE for os x to be able to make changes on a hard drive formatted in NTFS (Windows) https://osxfuse.github.io

Comment: Formatting the hard drive is all ways destroying data that is where fuse for os x is usefull it gives Mac OS X the ability to read and write to a hard drive formatted for windows without destroying any data